# How to use contains in JPQL

Tags: java, jpql, contains

I am trying to convert following LinQ query into JPQL. I am not aware about how to use `contains` in jpql. I tried like below But I am getting error

**LinQ Query Syntax**

```
var Rooms = from rooms in EspaceDB.Rooms
                            where roomIDList.Contains(rooms.nRoomID.ToString())
                            select rooms;
```

**JPQL Query Syntax**

I try:

```
@Query("select room from Room as room where roomIDList.contains(room.nRoomId.ToString())")
    List<Room> recoverDeletedRoom(@Param(value = "roomIDList") String[] roomIDList);
```

And:

```
@Query("select room from Room as room where contains(room.nRoomId,roomIDList)")
  List<Room> recoverDeletedRoom(@Param(value = "roomIDList") String[] roomIDList);
```

Error:

> antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node:

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@Query("select room from Room room where room.id IN (:roomIDList)")
List<Room> recoverDeletedRoom( @Param("roomIDList") List<String> roomIDList);
```